# Java Shortest Path Problems

Tags: java, shortest-path

I am trying to solve a shortest path problem.  IT is an old waterloo CCC question and I am practicing for 2019.  Essentially it is a "choose an adventurer book" there are N pages (up to 10000) each page can lead to Ni pages.  The first input is N, there are then N lines of input where the first number is the number of branches to other pages followed by which page it branches to.  If it is a 0 it is an end point and there are no other branches.  We have to state if all pages are reached and the shortest path.  Sample input and output:

```
input:
3
2 2 3
0
1 1
output
Y
2
```

I was able to solve the problem however, I keep failing the time limit tests.  How can I make my code more efficient to pass the time tests?  Here is my recursive method that I use to avoid cycles and get shortest path.

```
   public static void shortestPath(Page p, ArrayList<Page> list){
        ArrayList<Page> currentList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Page pg : list){
            currentList.add(pg);
        }
        p.visited = true;
        if(p.paths.get(0) == 0){
            currentList.add(p);
            Paths temp = new Paths();
            temp.aPath = currentList;
            completedPaths.add(temp);
        }else{
            for(int i=0;i<p.paths.size();i++){
                if(!currentList.contains(pages.get(p.paths.get(i) - 1))){
                    if(!currentList.contains(p)){
                        currentList.add(p);
                    }
                    shortestPath(pages.get(p.paths.get(i) - 1), currentList);
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Are you assuming we know what Page and Paths look like? (hint: we don't).
Anyway, since the graph is unweighted I would recommend implementing BFS.

Comment: Page class has two fields only, boolean for visited which I check off when that page comes up in the recursion.  Later I check if any are not visited to answer the first question.  The second field is just an ArrayList of Integers that contain the page numbers it leads to.  

For Paths it contains 1 field an ArrayList of Pages.  I made an object for it so I can have a list of pages that leads to an end.  I then have an ArrayList of Paths objects and later check which is the shortest.